# Will backdated posts show up in current feeds when posted now?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog like 'www.colorlife.com'. I want to update it with few backdated posts. Will these posts show up in the RSS feeds now. I **do not want them to show up** for some reasons. If they do, is there anything I can do to, not let them come up.

Comment: This question should really be on superuser, since it's no directly programming-related, but is computing related.

Answer (score 3):

backdated posts *will* appear in the feed. two ways to solve this:

1. date the post back so far that it is not among your 10 most recent posts (or whatever you set in settings > reading > syndication feeds show the most recent X posts)
2. install a plugin to hide individual posts from your feed. one i found working with my wp 2.8.4 is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-pauser/ .